# PDF Creator open source install package inno

Tags: vb6, inno-setup, pascal

I'm a few days researching and still not get anything that really helped me, I need to get the installer program by inno, my only problem is that I need to configure it so that at installation time he install the printer PDF Creator, I'm not getting do this part, I need while installing, install the printer pDF creator also need to change his name over that part I know more or less how it's done. If anyone can help me I thank you from the heart.

Comment: Ask questions only in English, please. If you prefer Portuguese, you can ask on http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ in your native language. Thanks!

Comment: What about simply running PDF Creator installation from your installation?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to either create a inno setup file (.iss) yourself or download "PDFCreator.iss" from the "setup" folder of source code version 1.3.2
2. Compile the inno setup file of your customized PDFCreator version using inno setup software.